# Explaining JSON (structure) .. to a business user

Tags: json, business-logic, sql-execution-plan

Suppose you have some data you would want business users to contribute to, which will end up being represented as `JSON`. Data represents a piece of business logic your program knows how to handle.

As expected, `JSON` has nested sections, data has categorizations, some custom rules may optionally be introduced etc.

It so happens that you already a vision of what "a perfect" JSON should look like. That JSON is your starting point.

**Question:**
Is there a way one can take a (reasonably complex) JSON and present it in a (non-JSON) format, that would be easy for a non-technical person to understand?

If possible, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think of this?
http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=90357&av=126401

Or, make your own using Ext JS for the visualization part.  After all, JSON is a lingua franca on the web these days.

Apart from that, you could use XML instead of JSON, given that there are more "wizard" type tools for XML.

And finally, if when you say "business users" you mean "people who are going to laugh at you when you show them code," you should stop thinking about this as "How do I make people in suits edit JSON" and start thinking about it as "How do I make a GUI that makes sense to people, and I'll make it spit out JSON later."

Answer (score 1):

Show them as key, value pairs. If your value has sub sections then show them as drill downs/tree structure. An HTML mockup which parses a JSON object in your system would help in the understanding.

Picked this example from JSON site

{
    "name": "Jack (\"Bee\") Nimble", 
    "format": {
        "type":       "rect", 
        "width":      1920, 
        "height":     1080, 
        "interlace":  false, 
        "frame rate": 24
    }
}

Name,format would be the tree nodes.